# JavaScript codePointAt and fromCodePoint give out different outputs

Tags: javascript

When i give a function fromCodePoint a parameter 1, i have "☺", but then when i try to recover this variable with a function codePointAt, it gets me out a number 9786.

```
console.log((String.fromCodePoint(1))); //☺
console.log(('☺'.codePointAt())); //9786
```

Comment: In Chromium based browsers `String.fromCodePoint(1)` returns `\x01`. Using `console.log()` seems to be what's messing you up here. There are a lot of articles/topics/discussions about why `console.log()` is bad for debugging, and this touches on that a little. The values you get are not always accurate. Basically your actual return value is being converted to be displayed in the console. `'\x01'.codePointAt()` or `String.fromCodePoint(1).codePointAt()` both return `1` as they should. You can also store the value in a variable and get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `console.log` is not reliable to display control characters correctly. *(**Note:** I do not have the problem described by this question on my Linux machine.)* However, the value is still correct. For example :

```js
const c1 = 1;
const c2 = String.fromCodePoint(c1).codePointAt(0);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = `${c1} === ${c1} is ${c1 === c1}`;
// -> 1 === 1 is true
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Similarly,

```
console.log('\x01'.codePointAt(0));
// -> 1
```

In other words, you assume the values are wrong because you are not using the same symbols.

- [U+263A](https://codepoints.net/U+263A)
- [U+0001](https://codepoints.net/U+0001)